# Problema con los cors nodejs

Tags: nodejs, ionic, express

Muy buenas tardes.
Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación móvil en Ionic y NodeJS me encontré con un problema en que al momento de tratar de autentificarme ocurre un error con `cors` y no me permite acceder a los tabs de mi aplicación.

Quiero tratar de solucionar este problema para comprobar si las fotos que tomo con la cámara de mi dispositivo móvil se insertan a una base de datos, podrían ayudarme en esa parte muchas gracias estaría agradecido de cualquier ayuda posible, para poder proceder con el desarrollo de la aplicación, en la primera coloco el código de

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
server.app.use( cors({ origin: true, credentials: true  }) );
app.use(cors());

//const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-COntrol-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
})
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: El valor de `origin: true` no debe ser un booleano sino un string, ya sea el hostname de tu sitio en este caso jelaapp.herokuapp.com o `*` para permitir cualquier petición desde cualquier sitio. En tu caso sólo seria `cors({ credentials: true })`

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando mal el argumento `origin` de `cors`, el valor de el argumento `origin` no debe ser un booleano sino un string.

Con esto es mas que suficiente

```
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Saludos Rimuru en este momento realice la solución que me pediste pero me sigue dando el problema de los cors, gracias por la ayuda que me estas blindado

Comment: @cristianmunoz también puedes usar simplemente `app.use(cors())` sin argumentos

Comment: Y esto `app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-COntrol-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
})` ya no seria necesario

Comment: tampoco funciono, le elimine lo que me aconsejaste pero me sigue dando el siguiente mensaje Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.2:3000/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
core.js:9110 ERROR

Answer (score 0):

Debes habilitar los cors del lado del servidor de igual manera.

Un tiempo tube tu mismo problema, al final me explicaron la función de los cors y me dieron la recomendación que se lo habilitará a mi backend y eso resolvió mi issue.

Comment: Si esta habilitado hice como el anterior compañero me sugirió y tampoco me funciono

Answer (score 0):

El problema no está en tu código, sino en la comunicación con el servidor, que está bloqueado con por el CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing), como programador de aplicaciones híbridas en Ionic, te puedo decir que este es un problema típico del framework. Como te comentan las otras respuestas, lo mejor es habilitar el CORS desde el API para permitir la comunicación desde un origen diferente. Puedes leer más información en la [documentación oficial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors) de Ionic.

Si no tienes acceso al API remota para la habilitación del CORS, puedes crear una API de pruebas y probar tu aplicación localmente. Sin embargo, para el stage productivo necesitarás habilitarlo SÍ O SÍ.

Saludos.

Comment: Saludos Alex en estos momentos lo solucione en si el error es porque me faltaba una linea de código para el token en el headers, gracias por la ayuda brindada

Comment: puedes compartir la solución? gracias.