# Access to XMLHttpRequest problema de Cors

Tags: nodejs, ionic, express, cors

Hola compañeros desarrolladores, tome un curso de Ionic 5 y al hacer uno de los ejercicios quise poner el backend escrito en JS dentro de github y heroku, al iniciar mi autenticación dentro de mi aplicativo me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi backend esta escrito en Express y node js. dentro de mi index tengo el siguiente código para la parte de los CORS:

```
// allow cross config
server.app.use( cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }) );
server.app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-token, content-type');
next();
});
```

al momento de hacer login el usuario crea un token, que se usa como header para futuras solicitudes http dentro de la app.

haciendo cambios tengo entendido que siempre tengo que hacer el CLI un push tanto en github como en heroku.

gracias por su atención

Answer (score 1):

Como estas utilizando NodeJS es bueno que instales la dependencia de cors y lo utilices como middleware para que evites el problema de cors.

Para instalar cors en node utiliza el siguiente comando:

```
npm install cors
```

Lo importas en tu index.js del lado del servidor:

```
const cors = require("cors");
```

Luego lo utilizas como un middleware haciendo que tu servidor lo use:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Con esto te evitaras problemas de politica de cors.

Comment: acabo de realizar los comentarios que me propusiste pero sigo con el mismo problema. muchas gracias por tu ayuda. de hecho hay un post con el mismo problema pero no puedo comentar para saber la solucion, dejo el enlace del post similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/335340/problema-con-los-cors-nodejs que es del auto @cristian munoz